# s3-storage-wagon maven plugin and upload to S3 bucket

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to upload my build artifact to S3 bucket. For this purpose, I'm trying to use s3-storage-wagon maven plugin

**This is my configuration in pom.xml:**

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
   <id>s3.artifacts.release</id>
   <url>s3://${artifactrepo.url}/release</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
   <id>s3.artifacts.snapshot</id>
   <url>s3://${artifactrepo.url}/snapshot</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
 </distributionManagement>

 <extensions>
    <extension>
        <groupId>com.gkatzioura.maven.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3-storage-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </extension>
 </extensions>
```

**settings.xml**

```
<server>
    <id>s3.artifacts.release</id>
    <username>Access key ID</username>
    <password>Secret</password>
 </server>
 <server>
    <id>s3.artifacts.snapshot</id>
    <username>Access key ID</username>
    <password>Secret</password>
 </server>
```

During Maven deploy this plugin fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project pipeline: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.xxx:xxx:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.xxx:xxx:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to s3.artifacts.snapshot (s3://my-backet/snapshot): Could not authenticate: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 8KJHKHFKHFGA48; S3 Extended Request ID: 2j/bW/INn+qCzVqwer+Fawv75qwerkUPmO7flQa8z34523445werrtwertGTs919tJpYoM=) -> [Help 1]
```

We are using GUI S3 client for Windows and are able to access the target S3 bucket without any issue. What may be wrong with our s3-storage-wagon maven plugin configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your AWS credentials for S3 do not have upload (PutObject most likely) permission.  The portion of the message telling you this is:

> Could not authenticate: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3;...

Or perhaps you need to setup your `~/.aws/credentials` file so that the `default` profile is able to access the S3 bucket you are using.

If you need to use alternate profiles (the non-default profile in your `~/.aws/credentials` file) you will likely need to specify the profile using one of the many ways AWS SDKs support this.  I would start by trying `AWS_PROFILE=my-profile` such as the following (assuming bash):

```
AWS_PROFILE=my-profile mvn deploy
```

See https://github.com/gkatzioura/CloudStorageMaven/tree/master/S3StorageWagon#authentication for further info on how to provide credentials to this plugin.